# How can I have optional parameters in Symfony2 route?

Tags: php, symfony, routes

I have this code below:

```
/**
 * Lists all User entities.
 *
 * @Route("/{cid}",defaults={"cid" = null},name="user")
 * @Template()
 */
public function indexAction($cid=null)
{}
```

Now if I type `site/user/1` then it works, but if I type `site/user/` it says:

```
No route found
```

How can I have it that both routes work?

Answer (score 81, accepted):

Try to go to `site/user` (notice no backslash at the end).

Generally it should work, I have relatively similar configuration working.

But if all else fails you can always define multiple routes for same action, i.e.

```
/**
 * Lists all User entities.
 *
 * @Route("/", name="user_no_cid")
 * @Route("/{cid}", name="user")
 * @Template()
 */
public function indexAction($cid=null)
{
```

Comment: Awesome, Thanks!

Comment: It was only a problem for a very short amount of time, but setting a default value on the parameter (`$cid` in this case) - very important :p

Answer (score 39):

Use a yml file for your routing configuration, and add a default value for id in your routing parameters like this:

```
user:
  pattern:   /site/user/{id}
  defaults:  { _controller: YourBundle:Default:index, id: 1 }
```

See documentation [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/routing.html)

Comment: The OP is obviously using route annotations in the controller

Comment: Yet his answer helped me and a few others

Comment: Notice for future: `pattern` key is deprecated in Symfony 3

Comment: ... and you have to use `path` key instead (SF3)

Comment: According to the best practices, should be the correct answer.

Answer (score 7):

You could also do it with a GET parameter, e.g.

```
/**
 * @param Request $request
 *
 * @return Response
 */
public function displayDetailAction(Request $request) : Response
{
    if ($courseId = $request->query->get('courseId')) {
```